# How to best allocate ranges of floats to a given value? Needs to be retraceable - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, physics, ordereddictionary

thanks for your time and help in advance.
I'm quite new to programming and curretly working on a physics simulation.

I work with Python 2.7

Say I have a list of zeros and ones that resemble binary numbers and these numbers are allocated with an angle-range - so the first number corresponds to the smallest angle and the last number corresponds to the widest angle. How can I tell my program best that it should also allocate the whole range between the angle-value of the i-th emelemt and the angle-value of the (i+1)-th element to the given value 0 or 1 at the position angle[i]? So that it's rather not like

```
list = OrderedDict[(angle1, 0), (angle2, 1), ...]
```

but

```
list = OrderedDict[(angle1 until angle2-epsilon, 0), (angle2 until angle3-epsilon, 1), ...]
```

and so on?

Until now I have worked with an Ordered Dictionary since the order is important and I could easily access values (always either 0 or 1) and keys (the angle / needs to be the angle range) seperately as needed further in the simulation, but I'm afraid that's not going to actually work with the ranges, since I already read that one can't hash lists (that has been my best idea but it didn't quite work out). The idea is to be able to retrace an arbitrary angle and get back the value of said angle-position.

Let me show you my idea here:

```
    thing = [[] for i in range(len(field)-1)]

    def frange(start, stop, step):
       i = start
       while i < stop:
           yield i
           i += step

   for j in range(len(field)-1):
        thingy = []
        for i in frange(field_angle[j],field_angle[j+1],0.0001):
            thingy.append(i)
            len_thingy = len(thingy)
        thing[j] = thingy
        del thingy

    thing2 = tuple(thing)
    print thing2


    gen = ((thing2[j], int(field[j])) for j in range(len(field)-1))
    A = OrderedDict(gen)
    print A
```

I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' as expressed above.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I do not understand really what you want to do, and your names are quite confusing: `list` is an `OrderedDict`? Could you give some examples how how the data in the dict is supposed to look?

Comment: It sounds like you want to linearly interpolate the floating point angles between all integer angle-values. Do you need to store all these angles in memory instead of just calculating it on the fly (which is not really costly)?

Comment: Sorry - Yes, "list" is an OrderedDict. I'll try to name stuff better in the future. What I would like to have would basically be an OrderedDict that allocates lists that contain every number between to fixed numbers and the value of that list, for example 1. And when I would have the input of one particular nummber, I could search in the dictionary fot the frange that contains this number and get the given value back. 
I actually don't need to store any of that data, it's enough to know the range and the value of said range. I actually doubt that my idea is that clever for the situation.

Comment: You write that the angles _resemble binary numbers_. What does this mean? What are `angle1`, ...?

Comment: You have a given angle range in which a "field" is emitted. Said field starts from (0,0) and is emitted in the z-axis. The virtual field consists of zeros and ones and is a binary code. Each zero/one is emitted in a very distinct angle within the given angle range. "angle1" etc are radian values.

The real life situation would be discribed much better if the zeros and ones would not be bound to such a distinct angle, but to the angle range between two of those distinct angles.